# Avoid duplication while moving/renaming binary file in mercurial

Tags: version-control, mercurial, tortoisehg

The mercurial move/rename commands seem to be delete+copy operations, this balloons a repository when binary files are just renamed or moved. With for example

```
hg mv foo.bin bar.bin
hg rename bar.bin goo.bin
```

repository now contains 3 identical copies of foo.bin. In retrospect the largefiles extension should be used, but assuming that files are already committed, is there a way to avoid this duplication?